# Carousel Control for Windows Universal Application

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone, win-universal-app, uwp

Is there any way to make a Carousel-like control that you could swipe infinitely to scroll the items?

I've seen that there is a CarouselPanel, but I cannot use it: it results in an ugly error message (look below for details)

EDIT: I've tried this in my XAML

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <CarouselPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <Button Content="Hi" />
    <Button Content="Hi" />
    <Button Content="Hi" />
</ItemsControl>
```

If you run this into a Page, you'll get an unhandled exception with this message:

> Exception = {"Unspecified error\r\n\r\nThe Panel you are using for
>   the Control is not allowed as an ItemsPanel for the Control."}

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Look at the edited post, please.

Comment: You still haven't said what the error is

Comment: An unhandled exception with this message: Exception = {"The Panel you are using for the Control is not allowed as an ItemsPanel for the Control."}

Comment: Unfortunately, that `CarouselPanel` can only be used within a `ComboBox` control. It's only enabled on a touch device. There's another control that might be helpful - `Pivot`. But you can only show one item at a time. Other than this, you will have to build your own.

Comment: @JustinXL Another bad thing: Pivot adds a header. In my case, need a list of products that the user can drag (horizontally)

Comment: You can edit its style to get rid of the headers.

Comment: @JustinXL that's a minor issue. The real problem is that it just shows a single item at a time.

Answer (score 1):

This control does not loop but I am sure, to make it loop would not take that much work. but it is a nice Carousel control

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2015/08/23/A-CoverFlow-control-for-the-Universal-Windows-Platform.aspx

Comment: Have you used it in production? A co-worker told me it's buggy :(

Comment: I have played around with it a little but not put it in a production app yet.

Comment: OK, I've played with it as well. However, it produces a very strange flickering effect when you scroll items faster than one at a time. Does it happen to you? Thanks